# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, datepicker

Does anybody have an idea how to find out which timespan the datepicker popup cuurently shows and how to apply additional classes on some days?

Comment: Please edit your post to include more details or at least what you've done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking I use moment.js for all of my date calculations / display.  That said, Angular does provide a decent enough date filter for displaying..